Besant's proof of Graves' Theorem
The proofs I have found of Graves' Theorem for drawing a confocal ellipse are analytic. I found an extremely short geometric proof as the solution to an problem in W.H. Besant's Conic Sections Treated Geometrically.


I don't understand the construction in the problem. The best I can is as follows but then the equation doesn't make sense.

I can follow the proof until the last sentence. The reasoning seems to be circular: to prove that the T is on an ellipse, I need that "TP and TQ make the same angles with the lines joining T and the foci". But that is true only if T is on an ellipse. In terms of the follow diagram, why is alpha_1 equal to alpha_2?


$\alpha_1=\alpha_2$ by the isogonal property of the ellipse (see Theorem 3.3 here)

Those equalities should be understood as valid only in the limit $t\to T$. In that limit we have
$$
\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}
PT=\arc{Pp}+pV=\arc{Pp}+pt-tV
$$
and from that the first equality follows. A similar argument gives the last equality, while the second equality follows from the length of the string being the same:
$$
\arc{Pp}+pt+tq=PT+TQ+\arc{Qq}.
$$
Finally, from the congruence of triangles $TtV$ and $Tty$ you get
$\angle TtV=\angle tTy$.
But when $t\to T$ line $Tt$ becomes the tangent to the curve at $T$, so that tangent makes equal angles with $TP$ and $TQ$. But $TP$ and $TQ$ make the same angles with the lines joining $T$ with the foci (isogonal property, see Theorem 3.3 here), hence the tangent at $T$ also makes the same angles with the lines joining $T$ with the foci, which is the optical property of ellipse. It follows that $T$ describes an ellipse with the same foci as ellipse $PQ$.
For a cleaner geometric proof, I'd suggest the book Geometry of Conics, by Akopyan and Zaslavsky (Theorem 1.6 on page 13).

Every time I read the word "consecutive" the thought of a limit crossed my mind, but I didn't follow it up...
